# Windows Client not getting updated from WSUS Server

Tags: wsus, windows-update

Please see PrintScreen1.png
[image: PrintScreen1.png]

As per Above Print-screen Computer qnit086v2 has 96% installed updates.

PrintScreen2.png

[image]

As per Above Print-screen '242 updates has not been installed'. If i click on '242 Updates' I get the below Print-screen and so on.

PrintScreen3.png
[image]

[image]

[image]

How to install all the uninstalled update. I tried various command such as wuauclt /detecnow. Is there any method to pull the update manually from WSUS Server.
Download should happen directly from WSUS Server.

[image]

Comment: Does the WSUS server have enough space? What's its synchronization schedule?

Comment: You probably don't have enough space to store all those updates. I only have Windows XP/7 with Office downloading and it's well over 50 GB used. If you expand the WSUS drive you should see it download more.

Comment: Correction - Thanks Nathan for your quick reply. The WSUS server has 5 GB of Free space left out of 50 GB where 'Database' & 'UpdateSource' folder is there. The Synchronization Schedule for WSUS server has been kept at 00:22 hrs. everyday

Comment: You need more space. The main window shows how much space is required for all those updates.

Comment: Nathan, I just made correction in my sentence. i.e 5GB free space is left out of 50 GB

Answer (score 5):

I realize this is an older question, but still might benefit others.

WSUS only tells you what the "Windows Update Agent" tells it.
So usually, to troubleshoot update problems on clients, *you need to troubleshoot them on the **client***

Usually, what you do is (on the client!):

- Stop Windows Update Agent `net stop wuauserv`
- Delete the `C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution` folder
- Start Windows Update Agent (see above.. you'll figure it out)
- Start a scan `wuauclt /detectnow`
- If you still don't get the update on the client, look through `C:\Windows\system32\WindowsUpdate.log`

Also, if your computer were `Imaged`, and you forgot to clean out the WSUS ID on the Client before creating the image, make sure you delete these values from the key: `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate`

```
SusClientId
SusClientIdValidation
```

Do this *before* doing the "Reset" above then.